# Xcode Matching Pairs of Braces, Parentheses, and Brackets

Tags: xcode, notepad++, matching, parentheses, braces

If you are a notepad++ user you will understand what I want Xcode to do for me , it's very simple I want when i place the cursor before or after a Braces, Parentheses, and Brackets , it highlight for me its pair to know the matching ones juste try to place the cursor in notepad++ and tell me how to do that in Xcode i know already the trick of the right arrow of the keyboard and the double click but the trick of notepad++ is faster , thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can add (and I have looked a fair bit) is to train your eyes on the vertical grey bar on the left edge of the editor, called the "code folding ribbon" in preferences. It will visually hint at matching braces (not parenthesis) at all nested levels, and mousing over it hints quite strongly and gives the interface for folding.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/MatchingPairsofDelimiters.html) for a snapshot and brief description from Apple.